# Is the Tk menu -underline option working on Windows?

Tags: tcl, menuitem, tk-toolkit, menubar, underline

I am working on a menubar using Tcl/Tk 8.6.12 running on Windows 11.  When I create a command menu item, the character referenced by the -underline *index* option is supposed to appear underlined and doesn't get underlined and the command does not execute.

I followed the tutorial on TkDocs (https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) to attempt even the simplest of menus, and the -underline option is not working as documented.

Am I missing or overlooking something?  No errors are generated.  Does this option even work with Windows?

The following demonstrates the simplest of menus.

```
package require Tk

option add *tearOff 0

menu .menubar
. configure -menu .menubar

set b .menubar
menu $b.file

$b add cascade  -menu $b.file   -label File

# The -underline option should under line the letter N
$b.file add command -label "New File" -underline 0 -accelerator "Ctrl + N" -command "CreateNewFile"
$b.file add separator
$b.file add command -label "Exit" -command exit
```

Comment: In reference to your title question, does it work on windows? Yes, at least in python.  I had it working on windows recently, it was not what I was after and hence don't have any code for you.

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but you might need to press `Alt` to get the underline to show up, a platform-specific rule.